# Adding empty column for 20 rows before existing column in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

Today I am facing an issue which might be very easy, but for me its difficult because I'm not proficient in VBA.

The scenario is that when I insert entire column and then copy a column to that column, then my Excel file becomes several MB in size. Actually, I want to minimize file space so that it can be shared easily.

**My question**: Is there any way to copy and paste a column for specific rows - not for all rows, because in this way file is of several KB in size instead of MB.

Please suggest an efficient solution to reduce file size.

Comment: `Please suggest efficient solution to reduce file size` Record a macro and see what code do you get when you do a `PasteSpecial Values`

Comment: For the record, it looks like you've asked number of questions on this site without ever accepting an answer. If you find that an answer to any of your questions is particularly helpful, [please accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179372), as this helps others find those answers more quickly, should they face the same problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on the macro recorder, do what you want, and look at the code that is generated, you will be able to see how to do this in VBA.

Specifically the first thing you want to do is use .Insert method on the range object with the argument Shift:=xlToRight to make space, then copy the range into the newly cleared space using .Copy and .Paste, for example

```
Range("C1:C2").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1:A2").Copy
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```